# Multiplying some elements of a list by and constant and others by a different constant

Tags: python-2.7, lambda

I need to multiply first 3 elements of a list by a constant (say 0.3) and rest of the elements by a different constant (say 0.7).

Input:
A list of unspecified length.

```
experience_yrs =[2.328767123287671, 2.16986301369863, 0.4931506849315068, 0.7506849315068493, 0.5780821917808219, 1.5808219178082192]
```

Output:
A transformed list of elements being products of original element and constant.

```
[0.6986301369863014, 0.650958904109589, 0.14794520547945203, 0.5254794520547945, 0.4046575342465753, 1.1065753424657534]
```

I tried this using lambda expression.

```
map(lambda x: x*0.3, experience_yrs[0:3]) + map(lambda x: x*0.7, experience_yrs[3:])
```

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: How come `x*1` changes value from `2.328767123287671` to `0.6986301369863014`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using a list comprehension:

```
[ x*0.3 if i<3 else x*0.7   for i,x in enumerate(experience_yrs)  ]
```